# How can I run C programs in sublime text 2 that require an input?

Tags: c, sublimetext2, build-process

I have created a build system:

```
{
"cmd" : ["gcc",  "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file_name"],
"cmd" : ["./$file_base_name"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell" : false,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

but when I run a program that requires a user input sublime doesnt let me type in an input.

Comment: You cannot. It's an EDITOR.

Comment: You can maybe fake user input with `"cmd" : ["./$file_base_name < user_input_file"]`